# python pexpect switching applications

Tags: python-3.x, pexpect

In python3 I am using the pexpect module and I am spawning the following:

`p = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash')`

If I were to send a command such as nano:

`p.sendline("nano cheese".encode())`

How would I be able to tell pragmatically that the spawn has opened up a new "ui"

Basically I want to know if there is a way to tell that the tty/shell has changed from /bin/bash to /bin/bash nano (or vi or any other application)

is this possible?

Comment: Typically, you would use `.waitnoecho()` to see if the application has switched off echo, as any UI would, but sadly sophisticated shells like bash now do the same. You could use a simpler shell, like sh. or call `termios.tcgetattr()` to see if other flags change. Or look through the output for typical escape sequences such as clear-screen.

Comment: @meuh thanks! side question (one of my many other questions on this platform that I am desperate to know) ... the output keeps giving me ansi code for its lay out... would you know how to convert this to html? Ive been using a python module but it leaves "artifacts" around if I do not put it into a file first. I am literally sending it from python to the browser (injecting) (sorry for spin off but i cannot find the answer, if you have ideas could we go to a chat room?)

Comment: I will look into a more simple shell if it will get me better results